# How to generate new variables for a kernel density of simulated poisson distribution in R

Tags: r

So I'm trying to generate new variable for a poisson distribution that subtracts the mean from each simulation. This is the original code I had to generate the kernel density plot of 100000 simulations:

```
x<-data.frame(P3=rpois(100000, 3), P9=rpois(100000, 9), P27=rpois(100000, 27))
data<-melt(x)       

ggplot(data,aes(x=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_density(adjust=4)+
  ggtitle("Kernel Density of Simulated Poisson Distribution")+
  labs(x="Random Variable X",y="Density (probability)")
```

Now I want to perform the same task but have the mean subtracted from each simulation. I hope this makes sense, very new to R!

Thanks!

Comment: The mean of the poisson distribution is lambda, so do you mean this: `x <- data.frame(P3=rpois(100000, 3) - 3, P9=rpois(100000, 9) - 9, P27=rpois(100000, 27) - 27)`

Comment: The `melt()` function you use in the second line requiers a special package. Which one? This will pehelp ople to understand to answer your question.